# using uploaded filename for ffmpeg input in php script

Tags: php, shell, upload, ffmpeg

I am looking for a solution to pull the filename recently uploaded and into this ffmpeg syntax

```
    shell_exec("ffmpeg -re -i ( Uploaded filename) -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://239.1.1.1:5000");
```

The above syntax works fine if I replace "(uploaded filename)" with a .ts video file. 
I have had a look around but there is nothing which fits this description.

my upload.php script

```
 if(isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']) && !empty($_FILES['uploadedfile'])){
  $target_path = "upload/";
  $target = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
  }
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] , $target))
  {
   $_SESSION['upload_success'] = "File successfully uploaded.";

   shell_exec("ffmpeg -re -i /var/www/html/upload/x265manual.ts -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://239.1.1.1:5000");
```

This works fine for playing back x265manual.ts after file upload, but i would like the system to obtain the file name from the uploaded filename.

Is this possible ? 
Would it be easier for me to create a new php file for the ffmpeg syntax ?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Just replace "/var/www/html/upload/x265manual.ts" in your exec with the variable containing the filename. And watch out for filenames containing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Add `basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])` where the specific file name goes.  If the `$_FILE` variable is in this same `.php` file already, it will always match the name of the file since it was just uploaded to the server.

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -re -i /var/www/html/upload/" . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://239.1.1.1:5000");
```

Comment: Sorry, I just spent 30 minutes helping the asker with the same file in a different question, so I was familiar with how his code was written.  I'll add something to it.

Comment: Thanks !  i had the basename ----- but couldn't get it working, never thought of putting the complete file name in.